# Textures in cycles render becomes "spotty"

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I am trying to render a scene in cycles. It looks fine in render preview (first picture). However, after rendering in cycles it comes out pretty awful (second picture). I have no idea why this happens and would appreciate any help.

It has been suggested that this could be due to displacement nodes, but I am not using displacement nodes.

[image: Render preview]

[image: Final render]

Edit: added node setup and render settings

[image: Node setup]

[image: Render settings]

Comment: Can you share your node setup?

Comment: I think this is happening because of your normal map; try reducing the strenght to 1 or if that does't work try rendering ater removing the normal map.

Comment: Have you removed your normal map as a test? Because of the distortion, normal/displacement issue.